# package.json know if there are any dependencies that are not used

Tags: json, npm, package, package.json

I have on a dependency project, I would like to know which of these dependencies is never used.

Example I have the following dependencies:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "d3": "^5.16.0",
    "d3-scale": "^3.2.2",
    ...
}
```

Let's say that in my project I have never used the dependency that I had installed the `d3`, I would like it to be reported to me.

How can I get a list of all dependencies installed but not used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/depcheck) for that.

```
npm install -g depcheck
```

Run in your project directory

```
depcheck
```

See the results

```
Unused dependencies
* chalk
* express
Unused devDependencies
* nodemon
```